# PHP code is not uploading file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

On the submit() event of the form, I'm trying to send the serialzedData to my PHP code for uploading the file using AJAX(both of which I'm new to). The PHP Code for uploading the file normally works if used directly without AJAX. I'm guessing its the AJAX portion that is not working...Any ideas?

Form(index.php)

```
<form id="upload-file" enctype="multipart/form-data">                                     
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" id="upload_button">                                    
</form>
```

JQUERY/AJAX(index.js)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var request;
    $("#upload-file").submit(function(){

        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }

        var $form = $(this);
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        request = $.ajax({
            url: "fileupload.php",
            type: "post",
            data: serializedData
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){        
            console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        });    

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){        
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrow
            );
        });

        request.always(function () {        
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

PHP(fileupload.php)

```
<?php       
    $fileToUpload = $_POST['serializedData'];   
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] > 0){
        echo("Error");      
    }
    else{
        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])){                                  
            echo("File Exists");    
        }
        else{
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],
            "upload/" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
            echo("File Uploaded");          
        }
    }
?>
```

And the directory structure is

```
-index.php
-js(folder)
    -index.js
-fileupload.php
-upload(folder)
```

Comment: What exactly happens when the upload fails? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No, no errors...it simply fails

Comment: Maybe you are not switching the $_FILES['image'] error properly. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php .

Comment: i kept alert() after each and ever line, and found out that after var serializedData = $form.serialize(); the line $inputs.prop("disabled", true); below are not being executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then try this new simply code in your index.php

```
    <form id="upload-file" enctype="multipart/form-data">                                     
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" id="upload_button"> 
</form>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $('#upload-file').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

 $.ajax({
        url: "fileupload.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "HTML",
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response){ 
            if(response == 'File Uploaded'){ 
            // do something
            alert ('0k file uploaded');
        }
        },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }

    });
       });


                    });
    </script>
```

and remove

```
$fileToUpload = $_POST['serializedData'];
```

in fileupload.php

Comment: you are sure that the dir where you want upload file have permission?

Comment: uptil now it did, but let me check again

Comment: i tried it on line & it works 
[link](http://disign.it/test/)
the dir where file are uploaded have chmod on 777

Comment: my index.js is in the subfolder called js, and in index.js im giving the url: "fileupload.php", whereas my fileupload.php is in the root folder, so does dot make any difference?

Comment: you dont need index.js only index.php with code i wrote and fileupload.php in the same directory. Because you set in fileupload.php upload/ as dir where to move uploaded file you need to set chmod 777 for upload/

Comment: Now its working...but i dont get the response, like you got over that link that the file has been uploaded

Comment: try this, modify


        success: function(response){ 
            if(response == 'File Uploaded'){ 
            // do something
            alert ('0k file uploaded');
        }
        },


in



        success: function(response){ 
            // do something
            alert (response);
        },

Comment: Thanks, the php echo was giving problems...solved it..and thanks for helping out

Answer (score 2):

As you are trying to upload files with ajax, then you should know that only with `FormData()` one can achieve that. So you need to change something like this:

```
request = $.ajax({
        url: "fileupload.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {serializedData : new FormData($('#upload-file')[0])}, //<----pass the form in the FormData()
        processData:false, // required
        contentType:false  // required
    });
```

With this line:

```
{serializedData : new FormData($('#upload-file')[0])}
```

You don't have to change much at server side. `$_POST['serializedData'];` will get the posted values.

Comment: So i just have to change the data part...any changes in the php side?

Answer (score 0):

In order to send the "file" object via ajax you need to create it as a object and send it, in that case i would prefer using plugin.
Using plugin is best choice for this.You don't have to remember all options.Just replace your 'ajax' to 'ajaxForm'.

plugin url:
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm

Comment: Plugins are fine but it's not a very good way to learn what's happening/

Answer (score 0):

try this
remove line

```
var serializedData = $form.serialize();
```

and replace data in

```
request = $.ajax({
        url: "fileupload.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });
```

with

```
data: $('#upload-file').serialize()
```

Comment: i forget sorry
in your php file  also remove
$fileToUpload = $_POST['serializedData'];